# Rails: Trying to render image of users with same attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, view, erb

I am making a yearbook application in Rails.  I am currently trying to display a list of images of all the Wdiers (this is a combo of teachers and students) that have the same `squad_id` as the wdier's profile page (aka the `show` view).  This would be rendered under the `squad_name` of the Wdier on the `show` page.

Here is the `show` view:

```
  <div class="squadGallery">
    <ul class="grid">
      <div class="index">
        <h2> <%= @wdier.squad_name %></h2>
        <% @wdiers.each do |wdier| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(wdier.img_url), wdier_path(wdier) %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I keep getting this error message:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Here is my controller for wdiers:

```
class WdiersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @wdiers = Wdier.all
  end

  def new
    @wdier = Wdier.new
  end

  def create
    @wdier = Wdier.create!(wdier_params)

    redirect_to wdiers_path(@wdier)
  end

  def show
    @wdier = Wdier.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @wdier = Wdier.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @wdier = Wdier.find(params[:id])
    @wdier.update(wdier_params)

    redirect_to wdier_path(@wdier)
  end

  def destroy
    @wdier = Wdier.find(params[:id])
    @wdier.destroy

    redirect_to wdiers_path(@wdier)
  end

  def wdier_params
    params.require(:wdier).permit(:name, :img_url, :squad_name, :squad_id, :quote, :teaching, :memory, :favlang, :wisewords, :tag_list,:github_url, :portfolio_url, :project1_url, :project2_url, :project3_url, :quote, :q1, :q2, :q3, :fb, :linkedin, :email, :role,  :student_id, :instructor_id)
  end
end
```

Here is my schema for wdiers:

```
create_table "wdiers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.string  "img_url"
    t.string  "github_url"
    t.string  "portfolio_url"
    t.string  "project1_url"
    t.string  "project2_url"
    t.string  "project3_url"
    t.string  "quote"
    t.string  "squad_name"
    t.integer "teaching"
    t.integer "memory"
    t.integer "favlang"
    t.integer "wisewords"
    t.integer "tag_list"
    t.integer "q1"
    t.integer "q2"
    t.integer "q3"
    t.integer "fb"
    t.integer "linkedin"
    t.integer "email"
    t.integer "role"
    t.integer "password"
    t.integer "squad_id"
    t.integer "codey_id"
    t.integer "student_id"
    t.integer "instructor_id"
  end

  add_index "wdiers", ["codey_id"], name: "index_wdiers_on_codey_id", using: :btree
  add_index "wdiers", ["instructor_id"], name: "index_wdiers_on_instructor_id", using: :btree
  add_index "wdiers", ["squad_id"], name: "index_wdiers_on_squad_id", using: :btree
  add_index "wdiers", ["student_id"], name: "index_wdiers_on_student_id", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "comments", "wdiers"
end
```

What will it take to solve the current error and display the list of Wdiers in the same squad?

Comment: What is the view file name where the failing bit of code belongs to ? Basically I think it says @wdiers is empty and therefore cannot pick any element . (Cause there's none)

Comment: It is the wdier show view. All the wdier data was migrated in through the seed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `show` action in the controller, you need to perform a search for the squad members:

```
  def show
    @wdier = Wdier.find(params[:id])
    @wdiers = Wdier.where(squad_id: @wdier.squad_id).not(id: @wdier.id).order(:name)
  end
```

This will retrieve into `@wdiers` all of the Wdiers that have the same `squad_id`.  The Wdier on the `show` page is left out of the squad list, because that Wdier is already displayed on the `show` page.  The list of Wdiers is sorted by `name`, just like a yearbook.

Answer (score 2):

In all of your controller actions you seem to define either @wdier or @wdiers. But in the view file you call both.

Comment: I used '<% @wdiers.each do |wdier| %>' to call each of the wdiers that have that attribute. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Nope, cause your show action is: def show
    @wdier = Wdier.find(params[:id])
  end. You need to create a wdiers variable as well as Michael has described

Comment: Michael actually tries to follow your logic to retrieve all wdiers with the same squad_id. To achieve this he takes the squad_id of the wdier that is passed to the Show action (show action is generally used to show a single element of a model) and add another variable called wdiers to retrieve all other elements with same squad_id. Yet I would recommend to create a model called "squad", of which wdiers belong to. That would be easier, the Show action for this model could show the very squad, but as well all wdiers belonging to it, and some other useful data.....